# Получение большого количества характеристик товара и последующая запись в базу данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, psycopg2

Нужно получить у поставщика характеристики товаров и группы этих товаров. Поставщик предоставляет три функции.

Возвращает список всех групп без иерархии или список только код товарного направления (самый верхний уровень иерархии).

#### Возвращает список словарей(характеристик) в которых есть:

"Nо" - id товара

"PropertyID" - id характеристики.

... и атрибуты характеристики.

**Возвращает список товаров (словарей) и их атрибуты:**

"Nо" - id товара

"GroupCode1" - код товарного направления

"GroupCode2" - код товарной группы

"GroupCode3" - код товарной подгруппы

Записать в базу мне нужно все характеристики с группой товара максимально низкого уровня. То есть, если у товара "GroupCode3" == None, тогда взять `GroupCode2`, если `GroupCode2 == None` тогда взять `GroupCode1`.

Я получаю весь товар по "GroupCode1" (3800 товаров).

Получаю все характеристики по "GroupCode1" (340 тыс. характеристик)

Двумя циклами обхожу и проставляю группу в таблицу с характеристиками.

Это происходит очень долго. И это только 1 группа, а их около 30 и мне надо загрузить все. Оставлял на ночь скрипт, съел 1,6 гб оперативки и завис. загрузил только 54 тыс характеристик.

Как это ускорить..? Поможет ли pandas в этом случае ? Или может есть другие варианты ?

Я новенький в python и не знаю всего. Прошу помощи.

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Pandas поможет в данном случае. Приведите в вопросе небольшие примеры входных данных (по 5-7 записей) для всех функций / типов данных и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе. Входные данные (списки словарей) лучше привести в текстовом виде, чтобы код можно было скопировать...